# Use of modal verbs in narration

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs

I often come across the following usage of modal verbs in novels: "But Turing would die before completing and publishing his final musings". Why not simple past like "But Turing died before completing and publishing his final musings."? What is the name for this construction?

*Edit:*
I realized that I have chosen not the right example. A better one is: "Every morning he would make himself a coffee."

Comment: Using "Turing would die" means that the novel is not at the time where Turing has already died.  It is simply describing that Turing will die before completing and publishing his final musings, but in the time of the novel that you are at, he is still alive.

Comment: @Sweet_Cherry: I often read books by Murakami. There it is often used like "He would make a coffee...He would go to...". It somehow replaces the simple past form. This seems odd if it is only a view into the future from a past time.

Comment: Sometimes authors or directors will use this as a summary to conclude a scene or chapter. In some cases it could be a cliffhanger.

Comment: @Sweet_Cherry: I don't think its the case, in "Norwegian Wood" Murakami is using this continuously.

Comment: Murakami wrote in Japanese. The translator may have used this construction to try to convey what was written in Japanese. But Murakami didn't really make that choice.

Comment: @ThePhoton: You are right, I should have said the translator. But is this a valid construction or an oddity only to convey something which is typical in the Japanese language?

Comment: I don't remember enough of the book to say. Maybe he's talking about things the guy wants to do, but doesn't actually do.

Comment: Maybe he's talking about something the character did habitually? He would make a coffee at a certain time every day, or in certain circumstances?

Comment: @KateBunting: Yes, this is the case! But why is one using „would“ in such a case? This relates exactly to my question

Comment: There are many different uses of 'would' - see https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would
 This use is listed there under 'Frequency'. The Turing example is a different use, implying that at the period being considered his death was still in the future.

Comment: @KateBunting the Frequency case was the case I was looking for. Can you turn this into an answer and I will checkmark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/would lists the numerous uses of 'would'. The first one (to refer to future time from the point of view of the past) fits the quotation about Turing. The one listed under 'Frequency' fits the other quotation 'He would make a coffee...'

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of 'would' in the sentence "Every morning he would make himself a coffee." is similar to 'used to'.
I found this explanation in Rene Bosewitz' *Penguin Students' Grammar of English*, page 119 (10 Modal Verbs and Modal Verb Phrases; Irregular Modals; 10.27. Used to).